# What are some better alternatives for nested when otherwise?

Tags: mule, dataweave

Many a times I come across situations where I have to use nested `when otherwise`.
That is, after an expression evaluates to true in a condition, I have to check for another condition.

Is the nested `when otherwise` a good practice or are there better alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the situation, you can group those like any other boolean checks. Some can be combined with `and`, others with `or`, some with `not`. It can be helpful to group the boolean checks into a group of functions with a descriptive name.

An alternative to `when/otherwise` is pattern matching, which is available in DataWeave 1.0, but I cannot find the docs for it. Here are the docs for 2.0: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.1/dataweave-pattern-matching

And here is an example of pattern matching on a boolean expression in 1.0:

```
5 match {
  n when n < 5 -> "number is less than 5"
  n when n > 5 -> "number is greater than 5"
  default      -> "number is 5"
}
```

You can replace `n < 5` and `n > 5` with function calls that return a boolean instead.

Comment: May be I did not convey it properly. Here is what I mean: `("x" when expression2 otherwise "y") when (expression 1) otherwise ("xx" when expression 3 otherwise "yy")` I am not sure if this sort of condition can be written using pattern matching. Ah may be another condition to the right of the arrow. But may be not very elegant.

Comment: I think you conveyed it properly. I'm just listing off your options in terms of organizing boolean logic in DataWeave. You can either 1) inline when/otherwise 2) group when/otherwise into functions and call those instead or 3) use pattern matching with options 1 and 2.